# half-daily rollover in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2, properties-file

Half-daily rollover for log4j2 not working for the given propertie file.

```
status = error
name = Proper

property.filepath = C\:/xi/doc/home/new/log
property.filename1 = ${filepath}/Common.log

filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level = debug

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p [%C].%M %m %n

appender.rolling1.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling1.name = RollingFile1
appender.rolling1.fileName = ${filename1}
appender.rolling1.filePattern = ${filepath}/Common.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-a}.%i.log.gz
appender.rolling1.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling1.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %5p [%C].%M %m %n
appender.rolling1.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling1.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling1.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling1.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling1.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling1.policies.size.size = 100MB
appender.rolling1.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling1.strategy.max = 20
appender.rolling1.strategy.delete.type = Delete
appender.rolling1.strategy.delete.basePath = ${basePath}
appender.rolling1.strategy.delete.maxDepth = 10
appender.rolling1.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.type = IfLastModified

# Delete all files older than 1 day
appender.rolling1.strategy.delete.ifLastModified.age = 1d

# loggers
logger.name = common
logger.level = debug
logger.additivity = false
logger.appenderRefs = rolling1
logger.appenderRefs.level = debug
logger.appenderRef.rolling1.ref = RollingFile1
```

The rollover works hourly and minutely if interval given and filepattern is given as `${filepath}/Common.%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}` and `${filepath}/Common.%d{yyyy-MM-HH-minutely}`

How to rollover half-daily? Is it supported in log4j2?

Comment: "Half-daily rollover for log4j2 not working for the given propertie file." - and it is a secret how it does not work? You now have to make me scan through that stuff to realise you are using the "AM/PM" trick that I had in mind by specifying the "a" formatting rule in the file date pattern, you could have explained that you know. So what happens now and how does that differ from what you want to happen? Do you get an error?

Comment: its not rolling over at 12 noon only rollover occurs every midnight @Gimby

Answer (score 0):

Log4j 1.x used to check at every message if the file pattern resolved to a different file name and rotated if it did.

However Log4j 2.x uses another approach. The date pattern is used twofold:

- the date pattern `%d{yyyy-MM-dd-a}` is used to determine the rollover frequency (cf. [source code](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/57cfe28541d418fa482b2ed75c32ea152fb03655/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/PatternProcessor.java#L310)), which in this case is **days**. This determines the time of the next rollover.
- the date pattern is also used to determine the name of the file, which would contains `AM` in the morning and `PM` in the afternoon.

If you want two daily rotations you really need to add an hour specifier to the pattern: e.g. `%d{yyyy-MM-dd-Ka}` and set `interval` to 12.

Comment: using `%d{yyyy-MM-dd-Ka}` rollover the log like this: `Common.2022-02-10-11AM.1.log.gz` , any clue how to remove 11 and just use AM or PM?

Comment: How would a daily roll over be determined? is it at midnight?

Comment: Yes, the rollover occurs at the end of the smallest time period specified in the pattern.